# Pandas - remove row similar to other row

Tags: python, pandas

I need to remove all rows from a pandas.DataFrame, which satisfy an unusual condition.

In case there is an exactly the same row, except for it has Nan value in column "C", I want to remove this row.

Given a table:

```
A    B    C      D
1    2    NaN    3
1    2    50     3
10   20   NaN    30
5    6    7      8
```

I need to remove the first row, since it has Nan in column C, but there is absolutely same row (second) with real value in column C.

However, 3rd row must stay, because there're no rows with same A, B and D values as it has.

How do you perform this using pandas? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve in using `drop_duplicates`.

Initial `DataFrame`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], data=[[1,2,None,3],[1,2,50,3],[10,20,None,30],[5,6,7,8]])

df    
        a   b   c   d
    0   1   2 NaN   3
    1   1   2  50   3
    2  10  20 NaN  30
    3   5   6   7   8
```

Then you can sort `DataFrame` by column `C`. This will drop `NaN`s to the bottom of column:

```
df = df.sort_values(['c'])

df
        a   b   c   d
    3   5   6   7   8
    1   1   2  50   3
    0   1   2 NaN   3
    2  10  20 NaN  30
```

And then remove duplicates selecting taken into account columns ignoring `C` and keeping first catched row:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(['a','b','d'], keep='first')

    a   b   c   d
3   5   6   7   8
1   1   2  50   3
2  10  20 NaN  30
```

But it will be valid only if `NaN`s are in column `C`.

Comment: So elegant and so simple! Thank you :)

Comment: Could you please explain what would happen in case there're NaN values not only in column C?

Comment: when you use drop_duplicates, you select columns to take into account. 
So in our case if in a duplicated row in column a,b or d there was `NaN` instead of same value as in free of `NaN`s row, it wouldn't be counted as duplicate, because `NaN` doesn't equal any number.

Answer (score 2):

You can try fillna along with drop_duplicates

```
df.bfill().ffill().drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B', 'D'], keep = 'last')
```

This will handle the scenario such as A, B and D values are same but C has non-NaN values in both the rows.
You get

```
    A   B   C   D
1   1   2   50  3
2   10  20  Nan 30
3   5   6   7   8
```

Comment: df.bfill() will fill all `NaN`s in this case

Comment: Yes, but it would be flawed to assume that all the NaNs are after the true value in the actual dataset

Comment: That's a very strong assumption. Initially, rows may be randomly arranged.

Comment: well, I think if there's no such task to fill `NaN`s, then we shouldn't do it=)
Or else it might cause problems in further analysis.
In this case all changes are visible, but if you have couple of millions of rows? Artificial value will make data more dirty.

Answer (score 2):

This feels right to me

```
notdups = ~df.duplicated(df.columns.difference(['C']), keep=False)
notnans = df.C.notnull()

df[notdups | notnans]

    A   B     C   D
1   1   2  50.0   3
2  10  20   NaN  30
3   5   6   7.0   8
```